# Батьківщина і вітчизна. Чому два слова, і звідки друге?

Tags: вживання-слів, етимологія, різниця-між-словами

З першим словом проблем наче немає. Батько -> Батьківщина.

А от друге здається криво запозиченим.

Що таке вітчизна? Країна "вітчима"? Росіянізм?

Сум має в собі ["вітчизну"](http://sum.in.ua/s/vitchyzna), але щось мене це не аж занадто переконує в правильності й доречності слова.

Буду вдячний тому, хто зможе пояснити, як воно сталося, що в українській з’явилося це слово. Може, я помиляюся?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Було таке праслов'янське слово `*оtьсь`, від якого пішли *отець, отец, оцец, отац, óčе, otec, оjсiес*..., а також (укр.) *вітець*, (в.-луж.) *wótc, wóćec*, (н.-луж.) *wóśc*.

Оце початкове "в" називають **протетичним "в"**. Ця цікава риса характерна для нашої мови та для лужицьких мов (до речі, подивіться на карту, лужичани  мешкають від нас на відстані 1000 км).

> Однією з особливостей української мови, яка одразу кидається у вічі
> при порівнянні масиву лексики з іншими слов’янськими, є так звана
> протеза (від гр. виставлення). Сучасна українська мова знає три
> протетичні приголосні:

> 1. `[j]` перед `[i]`, `[e]` та `[a]` (*їсти, єврей, ягня*);
> 2. `[w]` перед `[i]`, що розвинувся з `[o]`, перед `[u]` та `[o]` (*вікно, вулиця, вогонь*);
> 3. рідко коли `[ɦ]` перед `[o]`, `[a]` та `[y]` (*гострий, гармата, гикавка*).

> Спостерігається діалектна різноманітність у
> вживанні протетичних приголосних та відсутність єдиних чітких
> закономірностей. Протетичні приголосні можуть конкурувати (як `[v]` з
> `[ɦ]`), або поширюватися на переважну більшість говорів української мови
> (`[w]`). [Джерело](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/51887.html)

*Вогонь, восьмий, вухо, вікно, він, вус*... і, як ви вже здогадалися, **вітець, вітчим** :-).
Тому говорити, що *"вітець"* це запозичення, трохи недоречно.

Щодо *"отчизни"*, це давнє книжне слово, воно є у давньоукраїнських літературних пам'ятках, з часом воно трансформувалося у *"вітчизну"*. Суфікс `-изна` є одним зі словотворчих інструментів нашої мови (*жовтизна, білизна, дороговизна, польщизна, сивизна* тощо), тому не бачу жодної причини відмовлятися від цього українського слова.

Answer (score 7):

Вітчизна — таке ж українське слово, як і Батьківщина.

Наприклад, у творчості українського поета та мовознавця Івана Світличного [є такі рядки](http://maysterni.com/publication.php?id=31832):

> Вітчизна — це не хтось і десь, Я — теж Вітчизна.

Тому сміливо можна використовувати будь-яке із цих слів.