# Ні́где/нігде́. До якого(их) діалекту(ів) відноситься застарілий прислівник і яка функція (походження) літери "г" у цьому слові?

Tags: діалекти, діалектизми

СУМ-11 зазначає, що **ні́где**/**нігде́** - застарілі варіанти [ні́де/ніде́](http://sum.in.ua/s/nide)  відповідно.

> *ні́де*, заст. *ні́где*, присл., тільки з інфін. ...
>   *ніде́*, заст. *нігде́*, присл....

Мар'яна Бойчук у роботі [Гуцульсько-бойківсько-лемківські лексичні паралелі](http://spadok.org.ua/mova-i-pysemnist/gutsulsko-boykivsko-lemkivski-leksychni-paraleli) стверджує, що ***нігде*** (зі вставним ***г***) - це гуцульська лексема.

Водночас, зустрічаємо ***нігде*** у Євгена Гребінки:

> *Як не крути, а правди **нігде** діти:
>
>   Коли б, як виборного діти,
>
>   І другі вміли присідать,
>
>   То, може б, і вони зуміли так скакать* (Є. Гребінка “Хлопціˮ)

Полюбляв це слово й Тарас Шевченко. Відомі Шевченкові рядки:

> **з балади «Причинна**»: *Ще треті півні не співали,/ Ніхто **нігде** не гомонів; Цікаві (**нігде** правди діти)/ Підкралися, щоб ізлякать*;
>
> **з поеми «Катерина»**: *Нема **нігде** Катерини; Та здалась на горе!..*;
>
> **з поеми «Гайдамаки»**: *Лихо, люди, всюди лихо, **Нігде** пригорнуться...; Гуляють хмари; сонце спить;/ **Нігде** не чуть
>   людської мови*

тощо.

Ні Тарас Шевченко, ні Євген Гребінка не були носіями гуцульського діалекту.

При цьому, Лідія Гнатюк у роботі [Староукраїнське джерело мови Тараса Шевченка](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/new_books/Documents/kultura-slova-80.pdf) так пояснює походження ***нігде***:

> Наведені  приклади містять прислівник, утворений  *шляхом додавання
>   заперечної частки до поширеного колись
>   у староукраїнській писемності прислівника **где***, який для
>   тогочасного українця теж був функціонально українським.

**Тож до якого(их) діалекту(ів) відноситься застаріле ні́где**/**нігде́, і (*якщо можна*) яка функція (походження) літери `г` у цьому слові (вставна чи не вставна)?**

Comment: також заверність увагу на [nigdy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nigdy), [nikdy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nikdy), [někdy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%C4%9Bkdy). Але в такому разі дивно що 'нігде' а не 'ніґде'

Comment: моя бабуся родом з Київщини, дідусь - із Вінничини. Я лише нещодавно помітив, що я (як і вони) говорю не "ніде", а "ніґде", через ґ, а може навіть через к, "нікде"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Дозволю собі сфокусуватися лише на походженні `/г/` у цьому слові, тому що мені здається, що у даному випадку має місце не діалектизм, а навпаки, йдеться про цілком притаманне слов'янським мовам явище.

У фонетиці — не лише українській — є декілька фундаментальних явищ, які обумовлюють зміни у словах. Цими явищами є:

- **Діереза** — випадіння звуку при умові наявності деяких сусідніх звуків;
- **Протеза** — вставлення звуку на початку слова для полегшення вимовляння слова у поєднанні з попереднім словом;
- **Епентеза** — вставлення звуку між двома іншими для полегшення вимовляння цієї пари;

Як вказано у [цій відповіді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/838/8), сучасна українська мова знає три основні **протетичні приголосні**: `[j]`, `[w]` та `[ɦ]` (від себе додам: ще `[л]`, напр., *едва/ледве*).
Саме протерична `[ɦ]` і є причиною того, що існує пара *ніде/нігде*.
Стосовно `[ɦ]`, є ще пари *Анна/Ганна*, *армата/гармата*, *усениця/гусениця* тощо.

Варто зазначити, що діереза і протеза/епентеза нерозривно пов'язані між собою. Іноді навіть буває складно встановити, яка форма слова є «початковою», а яка утворилася пізніше (наприклад, у парі *она/вона*).

У даному випадку, Фасмер [вказує](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F), що українське слово *«де»* походить від ст.-слав. `къде`, тому варто вважати, що сучасне українське *«де»* — це наслідок діерези, а не навпаки.

Comment: Дякую. Власне, запитання й "вималювалося" з огляду на сумніви щодо "гуцульського діалектизму". Стосовно фонетичних змін, зокрема комбінаторних, то вони цілком можуть бути й діалектичними, хіба ні?. До прикладу, *горіх/оріх* - не діалектизм, а *воріх/оріх* чи *гогірок/огірок* - очевидні діалектизми. Хотілось з'ясувати, як у випадку з *нігде*.