# "Зайві" звуки у певних словах

Tags: вибір-слова

Чому в українській мові (особливо у представників старшого віку, які проживають на теренах Волинської, Рівненської областей) у вимові присутній звук «г» перед голосними у словах, що не мають такого звуку при написанні та літературній мові (гурок, гокно, гоко, Голька, Гандрій)?

Comment: Так-так, ще Гіталія, Гіван, мене завжди дивували такі поєднання і будучи дітьми ми щиро дивувались чого наші сусідки-бабці говорять так "по сільському".

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1351/ and https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/835/

Answer (score 4):

Це лінґвістичне явище зветься [«протéза»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0), «приєднання до слів переднього неетимологічного опорного або перехідного звука для зручності вимови». Протеза поширена в багатьох слов'янських мовах, зокрема, в українській (укр. «він» vs. рос. «он», укр. «гострий» vs. рос. «острый», укр. «вухо» vs. рос. «ухо», тощо), в білоруській (біл. «ён» vs. рос. «он»).
Волинські діялекти широко застосовують протезу, як от у ваших прикладах, проте не всі ці волинські слова увійшли в літературну українську мову.

Comment: Дуже дякую за відповідь!

Comment: @Anna2903, у нас тут прийнято дякувати методом голосування (upvote). :-) Якщо надана відповідь повністю влаштовує вас як автора оригінального запитання, ви можете також позначити її як Прийняту (Accepted Answer), натиснувши на прапорець ✔, який знаходиться під стрілочками голосування.